# Is there any way to change the currency?

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to make JPY (Japanese Yen) my main currency, since my business is in Japan.

Comment: JPY is now supported!

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We are actively developing support for selecting the Country, Language and Currency for each form.  You can track the progress of this feature at https://trello.com/c/yd97bUeA.  We anticipate releasing this support in late December to early January, as we are entering testing now.

We will support Japan-specific date and number formatting, Japanese prompts on forms, and Japanese Yen with this release.  Our Stripe integration will support payment forms in Yen as well, but at present Stripe does not support Japanese bank accounts.  However, if you have an account in one of the Stripe supported countries you will be able to process payments as well.

Comment: Our international release is now live, supporting most countries and currencies and 14 languages.